# React props being sent to a component appear as an empty array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am sending a state to a component as a prop like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
        axios.get("path/to/data")
            .then(result => {
                this.setState({
                    recievedData: result.data,
                });
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);

            });
}


render() {
    return (
        <MyComponent stuff={this.state.recievedData} />
    )
}
```

When I call `console.log(this.state.recievedData)` from this file I get the correct output (`0: id: 108, name: "foo" __proto__: Object length: 1`). However, in the file where I define `MyComponent` when I call `console.log(this.props.stuff)` I am told that it is an empty array (`[]`).

Why is the stuff property not transferring over to MyComponent correctly? Any ideas help. Thanks.

Comment: Where are the `console.log`s?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of `MyComponent` ,

```
useEffect(()=>{...},[props.stuff])
```

or if you are using classes

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
 if(prevProps.stuff!=this.props.stuff)
      {
          this.setState(...)
       }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked great. Just so I can understand, why is this? Because you need to tell it to update the props each time the state is updated?